# unable to install windows 7 from ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-7

so unable to install windows 7 i used winUSB, formated  the usb on ntfs the first time and fat32 the second time, i was following this
[How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

but i cant pass the second point "install windows" i have the partition of 69 Gigs but all i get is bootmgr missing, also i install ubuntu on legacy mode, this laptop aspire v5 came with win8 (which i totaly replaced with ubuntu14) now i want to have both ubuntu as main and win7 as secondary, apparently i cant share a folder via WIFI with my blu ray,( installed samba and gave permissions to share)

so im clueless now, please anyone?? needless to say that im completele new to ubuntu...

Comment: _"but i cant pass the second point "install windows""_. SO WHY? any error?

Comment: just that i go into the BIOS change the order so that i can boot from the USB, and boom  and i get "bootmgr missing is" im starting to think the ISO im using is corrupted or something

Answer (score 1):

problem solved by following [this](http://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html) and then just reboot on live CD and fix the grub

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [re installing the windows 7 boot loader](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/)?

Once you have Windows 7 up and running just [reinstall grub via an Ubuntu flash drive.](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

It's honestly usually easier to install Windows first, but this should work too!

Comment: on my previous laptop i had windows first, but with the UEFI bios everything is confusing and i opted for erasing the whole thing, now i cant even go back to factory and start from scratch again

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, windows needs to be on the first partition of the drive to boot properly. It may be a pain, but you may have to back up your ubuntu install.  Reformat your first partition to ntfs, install windows, then after completed install ubuntu on the next partition then apply your backups.  This should get grub setup proper for you as well.
If windows is already on the first partition, then reinstalling grub should do the trick.

Comment: yeah it seems i would need to reformat the whole thing again, i just hate it, this will be the third time, i have  windows7 ISO on a pendrive but im leaving this option to the very last

Answer (score 0):

this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html) might help you create a bootable usb and after that you can partition your disk with gparted to make space for windows, note that win7 creates a 100mb partition for boot files automatically so if your not using GPT make sure you have a max of 2 partiton already there because win7 requires 2 and mbr style partition tables allow a max of 4 primary partitions

Comment: I used Unetbooting and it doesnt seem to work, thats why i started using winUSB